# For loop based on two filtered columns

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new column ('Conf_Type') based on the Actual and Predicted columns. There are four combinations for the output of the Actual and Predicted columns: (0,0), (1,1), (0,1), (1,0) and I am trying to categorize them in a new column.

```
      Actual   Predicted     A         B
0         1          1  0.002753  0.997247
1         0          0  0.909696  0.090304
2         1          1  0.100924  0.899076
3         0          1  0.114059  0.885941
4         1          0  0.237289  0.762711
5         1          1  0.077710  0.922290
6         0          0  0.677748  0.322252
7         1          1  0.096327  0.903673
8         0          1  0.039741  0.960259
9         0          1  0.096884  0.903116
10        1          1  0.045345  0.954655
```

I have tried using a "for" loop, but it keeps getting a value error.

```
Conf_Type = []

for row in visual:
    if visual['Actual'] == 1 & visual['Predicted'] == 1:
        Conf_Type.append('True Negative')
    elif visual['Actual'] == 0 & visual['Predicted'] == 0:
        Conf_Type.append('True Positive')
    elif visual['Actual'] == 1 & visual['Predicted'] == 0:
        Conf_Type.append('False Positive')
    elif visual['Actual'] == 0 & visual['Predicted'] == 1:
        Conf_Type.append('False Negative')

visual['Conf_Type'] = Conf_Type

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I was wondering if a "for" loop is correct in this situation or that I should use another method.

Comment: try replacing visual with row in your if statements, that way the loop is only looking at one row at a time as opposed to the entire series

Answer (score 0):

You should use apply as I do here.

```py
number_meaning = ['true positive', 'false negative', 'false positive', 'true negative']
df['categorized'] = df['Actual'] + 2 * df['Predicted']
df['result'] = df['categorized'].apply(lambda x: number_meaning[x])
```

or use the function you defined:

```py
def meaning(row):
    if row['Actual'] == 1 & row['Predicted'] == 1:
        return 'True Negative'
    elif row['Actual'] == 0 & row['Predicted'] == 0:
        return 'True Positive'
    elif row['Actual'] == 1 & row['Predicted'] == 0:
        return 'False Positive'
    elif row['Actual'] == 0 & row['Predicted'] == 1:
        return 'False Negative'
df['result'] = df.apply(meaning, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# iterate every row by row number
for i in list(df.index):
    if df.loc[i,"Actual"] ==df.loc[i,"Predicted"]==0 or df.loc[i,"Actual"] ==df.loc[i,"Predicted"]==1:
        # set up the value of row 'i', column 'Conf_Type' based on this condition
        df.loc[i, "Conf_Type"] = True
    else:
        df.loc[i, "Conf_Type"] = False
```